# Update field from cross-object lookup fields

Tags: process-builder, field-update, cross-object

I'm having a requirement where I need to update a field.I'm having 3 objects

object1 -- Say suppose field1 is present

object2 -- fields having lookup to object1, object2

object3 -- Created field1 here. Now I need to update this field1 with the field1 of object1.

I have tried using Process Builder by creating on Object1 but I can't get the reference field (i.e., field1 of object3) in object1. Is their any other way to get this without coding. Or am I missing something

Comment: usual way to do this is have Process Builder trigger an autolaunched Flow which can do the cross object updates.

Comment: Any Example would be much helpful. I tried using reference but it doesn't worked out.

Comment: I should be able to do an answer later, but a bit busy with my actual job at the moment.

Comment: Sure no problem